# How to get the router values containing special characters in express router

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on to get route value in Nodes js using express framework

the url goes like

```
   http://localhost:3000/course/view/turbine/turcV39/%20V42/%20V44/%20V47
```

Need to get the value "V39/%20V42/%20V44/%20V47" from the above url and route

```
     router.get('/view/turbine/:turc?', function(req, res) {   
     console.log('a');
     });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to get it, like this

```
app.get(/\/view\/turbine\/turc(.*)/, function(req, res) { 
    console.log(req.params[0])
});
```